# Во второй форме авторизированная переменная $_SESSION['login'] пустая

Tags: php

Я на одной странице начинаю сессию и инициализирую переменную

```
    session_start();
$_SESSION['login']=$login;
  header("Location: AddPage.php");
```

а на второй странице я ввожу `$_SESSION['login']` и это значение NULL. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: А где код второй страницы?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я на второй странице не запустил сессию. Прописал `session_start();`. 
Потому что "session_start — Стартует новую сессию, либо возобновляет существующую". А новая страница - новый запрос.

Comment: Потому что "*[session_start](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.session-start.php) — Стартует новую сессию, либо возобновляет существующую*". А новая страница - новый запрос.

Comment: Чтобы дополнить свой вопрос, просим вас воспользоваться опцией редактирования. Кнопку «Опубликовать ответ» следует использовать только для исчерпывающих ответов на вопросы. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/201867)

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, это не дополнение вопроса, это ответ: `Прописал session_start();и всё заработало.`

Comment: @Visman если к нему дописать ещё, почему всё заработало, то точно ответом будет.